# Resharper Updating Source Files on Gulp Watch

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, gulp, resharper

I am trying to configure Resharper for Visual Studio so it's not reanalyzing dist files when they are built. I am using `gulp` to watch js files and build to `/dist` when they change. When that happens, Visual Studios becomes unresponsive and "Updating Source Files" appears in the bottom bar. Clicking on that pulls up a dialogue where I can see Resharper is loading newly built files in dist.

I've tried adding the dist directory to **Generated Code**, **Search & Navigation > Elements to skip**, and  **Code Inspection > Elements to skip**.

Still, Resharper is holding VS hostage whenever the build files change.

- Is there something else I'm missing?
- Is the skip directories apply recursively?
- Do I need to clear my cache or something?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm running into the same issue

Comment: Unfortunately not. The only solution I could find was to disable resharper for TS and JS :(